# Force application update without published in AppStore?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, upgrade, ipa

I submit my application on app store, but it took too long time in reviewing and they reject it several time for bug issue.

I upload the new version of IPA file on company's server, is it possible to upgrade application from IPA without accessing App Store?

Comment: Do you ask if its possible to launch a new version of your app without it going through review by Apple?

Comment: There is no way you can upload the IPA without AppStore if you still want it to appear on AppStore as well. 
You can use Enterprise certificate through which you can upload your app to your own server and users can download it from there (not appstore)

Comment: yes exactly .. once theres be a new version IPA file on server . application on iPad ask for update automaticaly (like update service in andorid )

Comment: @iosDev82 how can i do this ,, can you provide me a link ?

Comment: If you're getting rejected because of bugs, is it not a good idea to fix the bugs and resubmit your app, instead of trying to bypass the review process.

Comment: @ ABakerSmith yes i fixed them , but i want a temprary solution , until apple finished review  .. of course i would like to publish app on app store for non limited auduiance

Comment: @Meme.Rayan You can find some help here. https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/how-it-works/
and 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html

Comment: @iosDev82 i had made a lot of search , seems enterprise program also is not free .. need to pay 299$ per year ..true ?

Comment: @Meme.Rayan Yes. Enterprise programs are not free. Neither are the appstore ones. You have to pay for both of them. If you want to reach a limited audience, you can invite them by their email addresses as testers to your app.

Comment: @iosDev82 we paid for App Store and MFI since we use zebra library , but i thought it possible to upload same IPA on own server , but i released it need a different certificate and we shall pay for enterprise program , i decide to wait apple until finish review  .. thank a lot for your help

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is: **No. you can't**. The app needs to go through the [Apple app review process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_app_approvals#Approval_process).